# call a4j:commandButton from javascript on window unload

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, richfaces, onunload

I am not able to call `a4j:commandButton` click on window unload. my jsf code is here

1st the `javascript` in which i have window unload method and i have called button click in that function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        document.getElementById('pForm:closeTime').click();
    }
</script>
```

2nd i have hidden `a4j:commandButton` in body

```
<h:form id="pForm">
<a4j:commandButton id="closeTime" value="" action="#{controller.update}" oncomplete="javascript:window.close()" style="visibility:hidden;display:none" </a4j:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

when window is closed this controller is not getting called. Help me out in this !!!

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: IE 7 and FF 28.0 its not working on both browser

Answer (score 2):

It's much cleaner to use `jsFunction` for this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        closeTime();
    }
</script>

<h:form id="pForm">
    <a4j:jsFunction name="closeTime"
                    action="#{controller.update}"
                    oncomplete="window.close()"/>
</h:form>
```